# Does FIDE give titles to chess composers?

Tags: problems, fide, titles, composing

Does FIDE give titles to chess composers?

If so, do share more insight about the how-tos and other links to read.

Answer (score 8):

They used to, but now the titling process is handled by the World Federation for Chess Composition.

Here's a link to some of the titles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grandmasters_for_chess_composition

Answer (score 6):

The answer used to be Yes, via the Permanent Commission for Chess Compositions; in 2010 the Commission became the independent [World Federation for Chess Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Federation_for_Chess_Composition), but "both organisations are cooperating".  As was the case before 2010, there are three titles: Master, International Master, and Grandmaster, all based on the counts of problems and studies published in the [FIDE Albums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_Album).

There are also titles and ratings for chess problem solving, and a title of [International Judge of Chess Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Judge_of_Chess_Compositions).

Comment: @Arun J can you state that your question has been answered by either or both.