# Are there awards or titles for writing chess engines?

Tags: engines, titles

I recently found out that, in addition to the well-known titles for chess players, [there are titles available for chess composers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/13407/14122).

Is there such a thing as an award or title issued to those who have written especially good AI chess engines? I did some artificial intelligence scripting at university, and it occurred to me that I might be able to try out some of that neural net stuff to train up a chess engine that, while not quite reaching the level of world grandmaster, might win some local competitions or gain me some recognition on the regional coding circuit. Does such a thing exist?

I know that this is probably a pretty niche area, but if there are titles available for composers, it stands to reason that there might be some kind of recognition out there for those who have written some especially clever scripts (e.g. more than brute force "search the entire game space ten moves out" techniques that pretty much any programmer can write if they have enough time on their hands).

Comment: Cool, you can build on Alpha Zero.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are not. Engine chess does not have a governing body to award titles. There usually are not any prizes aside from bragging rights, either.

Comment: How about the TCEC?

Comment: @fartgeek TCEC doesn't award titles to authors though - only to the engine.